# Contacts plugin cordova not picking up contacts nor giving any error?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am new to the concept of hybrid app development and not used to any of the scripting languages like javascript.

I am trying to access the device phonebook via the cordova contact picker plugin but I am not getting any error nor acheiving the desired functionality.

Here is my view part from where I call the plugin api.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

   <link href="../lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">


<link href="../css/radio.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>-->


 <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="../lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="../js/emergency.js"></script>

    <script src="../js/services.js"></script>
 <script src="../js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-app="emergency">



<ion-view title="My Profile - Emergency" ng-controller="SmsCtrl">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
        <form class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label"></span><textarea placeholder=""> I am in danger</textarea>
            </label>
        </form>
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 285px; height: 34px;"></div>

        <button class="button button-light button-icon button-small icon ion-android-add-circle" ng-click="doContactPicker()">Emergency contacts</button>
<div id="contactFetched"></div>


    </ion-content>
</ion-view>


  </body>
</html>
```

The two js files that I have written are emergency.js and services.js

Here is my **emergency.js** which consists of the controller that calls the contact picker service:-

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
var finalContacts="";
var contactCount=0;
angular.module('emergency', ['ionic','ngCordova','NameService'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
.controller('SmsCtrl', ['$scope','$ionicPlatform','$cordovaSms','ContactPicker', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaSms, ContactPicker) {
  console.log('enetered in ctrl');
  $scope.form={}
$scope.counter=contactCount;
/*
calling the contact picker service : ContactPicker which returns the merged contact details of the contacts picked
*/
$scope.doContactPicker=function() {
console.log(ContactPicker);
$scope.answer='answer';
$scope.answer =ContactPicker.pickedContact();

 $scope.$watch('answer', function() {
        document.getElementById("contactFetched").innerHTML =$scope.answer;
alert('sample alert displayed');
 });

};



/*
function to add contact data to the array of items
gentrating new div items on button click
*/
 $scope.users = [];

        $scope.add = function () {
          $scope.users.push({ 
            firstName: "",
            email: "",
            mobile: ""
          });
        };


/*
function to send sms using cordova message plugin api
input : form.number and form.message
*/
  $scope.sendSms = function(){
    console.log($scope.form.number);
    console.log($scope.form.message);
     var options = {
            replaceLineBreaks: false, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
            android: {
                intent: ''  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
                //intent: '' // send SMS without open any other app
            }
        };
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
      $cordovaSms
      .send($scope.form.number, $scope.form.message, options)
      .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);

      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
    })
  }

}]);
```

And finally the **services.js** file

```
var finalContacts="";
var nameService=angular.module('NameService',[]);



nameService.service('getName',function() {
console.log("service created");
 this.nameFetched=function getUserName(c) {
console.log("inside picked contact");
    var name =c; 
    return name;
}
});



nameService.service('ContactPicker',function() {
console.log("service created");
this.pickedContact=function() {
console.log("inside picked contact");
//alert("inside");
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){
//alert("inside");
//      console.log('The following contact has been selected:' + JSON.stringify(contact));
//alert(JSON.stringify(contact));
        //Build a simple string to display the Contact - would be better in Handlebars
        var s = "";
        //s += "<h2>"+getName.nameFetched('yatin data')+"</h2>";

        if(contact.emails && contact.emails.length) {
            s+= "Email: "+contact.emails[0].value+"<br/>";
        }

        if(contact.phoneNumbers && contact.phoneNumbers.length) {
            s+= "Phone: "+contact.phoneNumbers[0].value+"<br/>";
        }

        if(contact.photos && contact.photos.length) {
            s+= "<p><img src='"+contact.photos[0].value+"'></p>";
        }

        finalContacts+=s;

        //$("#selectedContact").html("hello world");

    },function(err){
        alert('Error: ' + err);
        console.log('Error: ' + err);

    });
return finalContacts;
}

});
```

The control breaks on this function call `navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){`

using ionic serve i tested it on the browser but since the picked contact function would work on the device itself hence I am getting the following error in browser :-

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pickContact' of undefined

But with device debugging option I am not able to reach inside navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){ i.e no alerts inside this are displayed. 
Kindly help me resolve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At first, where is the reference to cordova.js? that is:

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Then, did you installed properly the [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts)?

Cordova plugins are available only on devices, not in the browser, so you have to install the built app on a device, connect it to your computer and debug via usb (in a way depending on the specific platform iOS/Android/...).

Comment: Thanks @beaver .
An additional Reference to cordova.js is not required. The ionic bundle has it covered already.I still added the reference but it didn't work. I understand that cordova plugins would work on the device itself that is why I tested it with usb debugging as well but I am not able to reach inside the navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact) function as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you know that if you want a plugin you need to install it. So to install the plugin you want (**cordova-plugin-contacts**) you need to install it with cordova. This will add the plugin in your plugins folder in your current project. The plugins folder is in the root of your project. Inside you should see a folder called **cordova-plugin-contacts** or **org.apache.cordova.contacts**. Otherwise you should run the command below.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-contacts
```

[You can find more info about installing the cordova-plugin-contacts here.](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts#installation)